# Could not clone or push to GitHub

Tags: git, github

My friend creates a private repo on GitHub and invite me as a collaborations. I accepted the invitation, but when clone from the repo or push the code to that repo, I got error `remote: Write access to repository not granted. fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/...': The requested URL returned error: 403`

My friend has setup the read and write access in the repo.
[image]

Could anyone help us? Thank you!

Comment: The screenshot you are showing are the rights of Github Actions work flows and is not related to user rights. Adding you as collaborator should be enough. Check that it has been done. Maybe the problem come from the fact that it is private.

Comment: It's weird that I could add the files in the Github user interface or modify the code there but could not perform any action via terminal.